# Unreadable Notebook: /home/kerwin/test2/test.ipynb AttributeError('metadata',) in Pycharm

Tags: pycharm, jupyter-notebook

I want to use Jupyter notebook for Data Analysis. When I follow the guide which is provided by jetbrains in: [Tutorial: Using IPython/Jupyter Notebook with PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/tutorial-using-ipython-jupyter-notebook-with-pycharm.html#d392072e13).
1. My working environment is Ubunutu I have install all the package:
anaconda and jupyter
2. When I just test it like :
```python

```
In[]: print 'hello world!'
```

```
There are some errors:

```
[W 23:13:33.681 NotebookApp] Unrecognized JSON config file version, assuming version 1
[E 23:13:33.690 NotebookApp] [nb_conda_kernels] couldn't call conda:
    [Errno 2] No such file or directory
[I 23:13:33.691 NotebookApp] [nb_conda_kernels] enabled, 0 kernels found
[I 23:13:34.381 NotebookApp] ✓ nbpresent HTML export ENABLED
[W 23:13:34.382 NotebookApp] ✗ nbpresent PDF export DISABLED: No module named nbbrowserpdf.exporters.pdf
[I 23:13:34.385 NotebookApp] [nb_conda] enabled
[I 23:13:34.598 NotebookApp] [nb_anacondacloud] enabled
[I 23:13:34.612 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/kerwin/test2
[I 23:13:34.613 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels 
[I 23:13:34.613 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at: http://127.0.0.1:8888/
[I 23:13:34.613 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[I 23:13:35.433 NotebookApp] Kernel started: 19c9b3d5-1c14-4487-bed0-aa351295467a
[W 23:13:35.464 NotebookApp] No session ID specified
```

Althoungh it have content in http://127.0.0.1:8888/, but it just say: `Unreadable Notebook: /home/kerwin/test2/test.ipynb AttributeError('metadata',)`

Before I tried like:
```

```
conda update nb_conda nb_conda_kernels nb_anacondacloud
```

```
But there are still problems.

Can you help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. You should use **save and checkout** after editing on Pycharm. And then run.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  If I created a notebook in pycharm, I would receive the same error.  However, if I created the notebook in the Jupyter browser first, and then saved it, it would appear in my Pycharm IDE.  Then if I edited it in the pycharm editor, when I would restart the Jupyter Kernal in the browser, it would update with my Pycharm edits.

Try this

- Open Pycharm.
- Start your Jupyter server
- Navigate to http://127.0.0.1:8888/
- Create a new notebook there.
- Do some code like print('hi')
- Save notebook
- Navigate back to pycharm and you should see that your project now has
  a .ipynb file.
- Open it and edit the file to say something like print('hey')
- Save it.
- Stop and then Restart the Jupyter Notebook kernal in the browser.
- It should be updated with the new code.

After I went through this process once, simply saving the file in pycharm would update on refresh in the browser.  No need to keep stopping and restarting the kernal